# iOS Safari memory leak makes Apps unusable

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I have an "editable table" in my web application. How it works is that when you click on the td of the table, I read the innerHTML of the td and generate an input field which I inject into the td with the value of the innerHTML.

When you blur/focus-out of the input field, I destroy the input field and set the innerHTML of the new value, as well as send an AJAX request to update that field. This works perfectly on desktops and android phones, but on iOS Safari it will get progressively slower the more values you edit. After approx. 250 edits, scrolling will become very choppy and eventually the page will become almost unusable. A page refresh does not fix the issue, it requires you to close the web page entirely and start again.

This leads me to believe that Safari is not releasing memory of the destroyed input fields.

The relevant JavaScript code is given below and is fired on click on a td:

```
_handleEditing: function($td) {
    var value = $td.find("span").html().replace(",", ""),
        ctrl = this;

    $td.unbind('click');

    // Clone the input control
    var $editControl = $('#input .edit-control').clone();

    if(this.isMobile) {
        $editControl.attr('type', 'number');
        $editControl.attr('step', '0.01');
    }

    // Inject editControl into td html and set appropriate values
    $td.html($editControl);
    $editControl.val(value);

    // Focus the edit control and set the selection range
    $editControl.focus();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $editControl.get(0).setSelectionRange(0, value.length);
    }, 0);

    firstKeydown = true;

    // Handle leaving the input field and returning to normal number
    $editControl.on('blur', function(){
        var newValue = $editControl.val();

        // If the newValue is empty, go back to the old value
        newValue = (newValue === '') ? value : newValue;

        var parsedNewValue = parseFloat(newValue).toFixed(2);

        // If the newValue is not actually a number, go back to the old value
        newValue = isFinite(parsedNewValue) ? parsedNewValue : value;

        $editControl.unbind().remove();
        $editControl = null;

        $td.html("<span>"+newValue+"</span>");

        // Queue this value update to server
        if(parseFloat(newValue) !== parseFloat(value)) {
            ctrl.handleValueChanged($td, value, newValue);
        }

        // Reinstate the click handler on the td
        $td.click(function(){
            ctrl._handleEditing($td);
        });
    });

    this._attachNavigationHandlers($editControl);

},
```

ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED.
APPLE DEVELOPERS PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 3):

Based on research I've been doing for a similar issue (gradual performance degradation on iOS, I've come across numerous sources that indicate this is a problem with iOS itself.

> The performance issue in iOS 9 seems to be related to a bug in Safari.  Whether you are using Safari, UIWebView or WKWebView...you will notice a hit in performance every time you select a text input field.  I created a basic html page with 100 text inputs...and as I traverse through the inputs a few times, the app eventually becomes unresponsive to gestures.  The only solution in Webview/Webkit (that I am aware of) is to restart the app.

Reference:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21956

As of right now, there does not seem to be a solution. In my case, I am force closing the app when the user logs out. Unfortunately, if you want your app on the App Store, you can't programmatically quit your app.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.